# Is there a way to insert right braces and text to the right of a matrix using LYX?

Tags: lyx, labels, delimiters

Is there a way to typeset this **in LYX** without using ERT?  If not, how do I code it in Lyx?

[image: Matrix with brace and text to the right]

Comment: I have seen that post but I am hoping a Lyx expert knows of a different, less lengthy way to do it in Lyx?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. LyX has built-in support for over and underbraces, but not for the side braces. In the future, it is helpful to me (a LyX user) if you reference the LaTeX solution in your question. That way I can look at it and easily see if I can think of a LyX way to do it.